# XSLT Sort by second element if first element equals zero

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I'm trying to sort some statistical information for use in InDesign and would like to do a conditional sort which uses a second element if the first has a value of zero. Essentially, I would like to sort the information by "shots/@sh" if "shots/@g" has a value of zero. Source XML below. Thank you.

```
   <player uni="9" code="9" name="" checkname="" class="" gp="1">
  <shots g="0" a="0" sh="1" sog="1" ps="0" psatt="0"></shots>
  <goaltype gw="0" ua="0" fg="0" ot="0" en="0" hat="0" gt="0" so="0"></goaltype>
  <penalty count="0" red="0" yellow="0" green="0" fouls="0"></penalty>
  <misc minutes="0" dsave="0"></misc>
</player>
<player uni="10" code="10" name="Ali Al-Gashamy" checkname="AL-GASHAMY,ALI" class="" gp="1" gs="1" pos="f">
  <shots g="0" a="0" sh="2" sog="0" ps="0" psatt="0"></shots>
  <goaltype gw="0" ua="0" fg="0" ot="0" en="0" hat="0" gt="0" so="0"></goaltype>
  <penalty count="0" red="0" yellow="1" green="0" fouls="0"></penalty>
  <misc minutes="82" dsave="0"></misc>
</player>
<player uni="11" code="11" name="Severin Soerlie" checkname="SOERLIE,SEVERIN" class="" gp="1" gs="1" pos="mf">
  <shots g="0" a="0" sh="3" sog="0" ps="0" psatt="0"></shots>
  <goaltype gw="0" ua="0" fg="0" ot="0" en="0" hat="0" gt="0" so="0"></goaltype>
  <penalty count="0" red="0" yellow="0" green="0" fouls="0"></penalty>
  <misc minutes="90" dsave="0"></misc>
</player>
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Stuck in 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would like to do a conditional sort which uses a second element if the
>   first has a value of zero.

How about:

```
<xsl:sort select="shots[@g!=0]/@g | shots[@g=0]/@sh" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

---

### Added:

> I basically just want to sort by goals first, but if we don't score
>   I'd like it to sort by shots instead.

That's a completely different requirement. For this, you should use two sort instructions:

```
<xsl:sort select="shots/@g" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
<xsl:sort select="shots/@sh" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

assuming you don't care if players with the same number of goals are sorted internally by shots, even if the number of goals is not zero. Otherwise use:

```
<xsl:sort select="shots[@g=0]/@sh" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

as the second sort instruction.

Comment: It worked, but for a game with a goal scored it bypassed the goalscorer and selected the player with the next-highest shot total. We're definitely on the right track though. I basically just want to sort by goals first, but if we don't score I'd like it to sort by shots instead. If that makes sense...

Comment: See if the added part makes sense to you.

Comment: That did it. My apologies for the confusion. I'm still trying to figure out how this stuff works. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it took me a moment to wrap my head around it. It's working beautifully though. Exactly what I've been trying to figure out.